# Anti-persymmetric Spinorial Matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, spinors, clifford-algebra

An antipersymmetric matrix is one that is antisymmetric about its anti-diagonal.

The simplest example comes from the Pauli Matrices:

- {σ[0],σ[1],σ[2]} are *not* antipersymmetric
- σ[3] *is* antipersymmetric.

Of course, σ[3] rotates democratically among σ[1] and σ[2]; there surely is no physical distinction here.  Even so, in some sense, σ[3] remains mathematically "special"...we certainly pick it out when constructing tensors, *etc*...

I've recently generated a set of tens of thousands of seemingly physically indistinguishable spinorial matrices of which *only one is antipersymmetric*.  Trust me, it is the most beautiful one by far; I am going to use it no matter what.

So, what is my question, then?   Not crystal clear, but something like this:

Has anyone seen any references to antipersymmetric spinorial matrices in physics or mathematics literature beyond the mere name?

Comment: DOI 10.1088/0266-5611/19/1/312      follow the refs...   https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11338

Comment: There's one more piece of literature than I ever found.

Comment: you mean [this](https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0266-5611/19/1/312)?